# Identify filenames with numbers over a certain amount in bash

Tags: bash

I'm trying to delete all files whose file name contains a number greater than 100, but have been unable to get the script I wrote working. Here's what I wrote so far:

```
#!/bin/bash

files=$(ls $1)
regex='test__(\d+).txt'

for f in $files
do
    if [[ $f =~ $regex ]]; then
        filenum=${BASH_REMATCH[1]}
        if [ $filenum > 100 ]; then
            rm $f
        fi
    fi
done
```

Debugging by placing various `echo` statements around the script, I've found that it never makes it past matching the regex. In fact, I can't even match strings of digits on the command line at all: `ls | grep [0-9]` will match filenames with digits, but `ls | grep [0-9]+` doesn't match anything at all!

Is there a gap in my knowledge of how bash handles regex? Or have I screwed up somewhere else in the program that's causing me issues?

Comment: Bash doesn't recognize `\d` for  digits - use `[0-9]` or `[[:digit:]]` instead. And grep needs the `-E` option to recognize `+` as a metacharacter, or it has to be escaped (`\+` - which is a GNU extension).

Comment: `grep -E [0-9]+` should work.

Answer (score 0):

No need for any script:

```
rm *[2-9][0-9][0-9]* *[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]* *10[1-9]* *1[1-9][0-9]*
```